# Smartfusion2 MSS SPI communication

Tags: c, spi

I am working with the Microsemi Smartfusion2 development kit from Arrow. It uses the Smartfusion2 M2S010-FG484 FPGA. (https://www.arrow.com/en/products/sf2plus-dev-kit/arrow-development-tools)

I am new to the Smartfusion2, I am trying to establish a connection between the Smartfusion2 FPGA and Arduino using the microcontroller subsystem (MSS) and programing ti in Softconsole. The problem is that I can't seem to get it to work. While trying to debug, I attached an LED (i had to improvise since I don't have an oscilloscope) to pin 3 of the arduino connector (J2) on the development board. This pin should contain the slave select 3 (pin J18 on the FPGA) as indicated in the datasheet on page 16 (https://static4.arrow.com/-/media/images/part-detail-pages/sf2-plus/new-sf2-files/sf2plus_user_guide_v1p1.pdf?la=zh-cn) and in the I/O editor of Libero SoC.

With the following code I am trying to toggle the LED/Select and deselect the specified slave (Slave 3). But nothing happens. The Slave select is active low but the LED is always on and never turns off.

```
    /*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 16, 2017
 */

#include "drivers/mss_gpio/mss_gpio.h"
#include "drivers/mss_spi/mss_spi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/*Delay function in milliseconds, for 100MHz clock*/
void Delay(uint32_t Delayms){
    uint32_t i = 0;
    uint32_t DelayValue = Delayms*2000; //1000ms*100000 = 100000000 (100MHz)
    for(i = 0; i <= DelayValue; i++){
    }
}

/*Configuration for SPI0*/
void ConfigSPI1(void){
    /*Initialize and Configure SPI1*/
    MSS_SPI_init(&g_mss_spi1);

    MSS_SPI_disable(&g_mss_spi1); //Disable SPI1

    /*Configure SPI1 as master, protocol mode, clk speed, frame size*/
    MSS_SPI_configure_master_mode(
            &g_mss_spi1,        //Selects SPI1 for configuration
            MSS_SPI_SLAVE_3,    //Set the target device as slave 3
            MSS_SPI_MODE2,      //Serial peripheral interface operating mode
            64u,                //Divider used on APB bus (PCLK) clock in order to generate the SPI clock
            12);                //Number of bits making up the frame, max = 32

    MSS_SPI_enable(&g_mss_spi1); //Enable SPI1
}

/*SPI0 test function*/
void SPI1Test(void){
    MSS_SPI_set_slave_select(&g_mss_spi1, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_3);     //Used by a MSS SPI master to select a specific slave
    MSS_SPI_transfer_frame(&g_mss_spi1, 0xaaa);                 //Transfers "0xaaa" to the selected slave (slave 3)
    Delay(1000);      // I used this delay for testing, to keep the SS low for a longer time to be able to see the LED turn off
    MSS_SPI_clear_slave_select(&g_mss_spi1, MSS_SPI_SLAVE_3);   //Used by a MSS SPI master to deselect a specific slave
}

int main(){

    /*Configure modules*/
    ConfigSPI1();

    /*Infinite loop*/
    for(;;){
        SPI1Test();
        Delay(3000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone see a mistake in my code that might be causing the problem? or maybe have an working example code for me?

I wrote another program to toggle pin J18/the slave select 3 pin with the gpio driver, and that worked, it toggled the LED. I am also pretty certain that the design in Libero SoC is correct and imported correctly.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So I came to learn that the Slave select can only be held LOW for a certain time before it automatically goes back to HIGH because of a time out standard of the SPI protocol. This causes the Slave Select to only stay low for a very short time (uS). This is too fast to see any effect on an LED, it just appears lit constantly. After i obtained an oscilloscope it became clear. So the code works :D